# build a list with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a drop-down menu:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option> select
    <option value="fruits"> fruits
    <option value="flowers"> flowers
</select>
```

When I select one of the options I need to build an un-ordered list from an array that I have:

```
var myFruits = ["apple","orange","banana"];
var myFlowers= ["rose","tulip","carnation"];
```

... and have the option become a header of the list, something like:

```
<ul>fruits
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>banana</li>
</ul>
```

I also need to allow to have multiple select, i.e. User can select both options from the drop-down. I'm trying to use jQuery but have not gone too far:

```
$("#mySelect").click(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "fruits") {
        $("#myResults").append("<ul>"+$(this).val()+"</ul>");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this(I have used change event, you can easily change it to use click event if you think you need to handle click function for sure):

```
$("#mySelect").change(function() {
                if($(this).val() == "fruits") {
                    var fruitsListHTML = "";
                    if($("#myResults").data("fruits") != "1"){
                        $.each(myFruits, function(a, b){
                            fruitsListHTML += "<li>" + b + "</li>";
                        });
                        $("#myResults").append("<ul>"+ fruitsListHTML +"</ul>");
                        $("#myResults").data("fruits", "1");
                    }
                }
            });
```

For a more generic solution:

```
    <select id="mySelect" multiple>
        <option> select </option>
        <option value="fruits"> fruits
        <option value="flowers"> flowers
   </select>
     <div id="myResults"></div>
     <input type="text"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
      var optionsList = {
            fruits: ["apple","orange","banana"],
            flowers: ["rose","tulip","carnation"]
        };

        $(function() {
         $("#mySelect").change(function() {
                var options = $(this).val();
                $.each(options, function(i,e){
                    if($("#myResults").data(e) != "1"){
                        var listHTML = "";
                        $.each(optionsList[e], function(a, b){
                            listHTML += "<li>" + b + "</li>";
                        });
                        $("#myResults").append("<ul>"+ listHTML +"</ul>");
                        $("#myResults").data(e, "1");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Wow, this looks great! So I assume I'll add this logic for each possible option, right? Thanks.

Comment: @santa: Yes. However take a look at alternate solution I have posted for a more generic approach.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use a jQuery template to help out with this as well.  For example, this would render the items in the list for you.

**Edit**
I modified this to also use an attribute on the selected option to identify which data source to use.

```
var myFruits = [
    { Name: 'apple' },
    { Name: 'orange' },
    { Name: 'banana' }
];

var myFlowers = [
    { Name: 'rose' },
    { Name: 'tulip' },
    { Name: 'carnation' }
];

$(function () {
    $('#mySelect').change(function () {
        var option = $('#mySelect option:selected');                
        var data = eval((option).attr('data-source'));
        $.tmpl('<li>${Name}</li>', data).appendTo('#tmpl-cont');
    });
});

<select id="mySelect">
    <option> select
    <option data-source="myFruits" value="fruits"> fruits
    <option data-source="myFlowers" value="flowers"> flowers
</select>

<ul id="tmpl-cont" />
```

[Here's](http://api.jquery.com/tmpl) some more information on templates.

Comment: If creating an attribute out of thin air, it's recommended to use HTML5's ```data-*``` attributes. You can read the specs here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes, and can read ejohn's great example here: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: @McHerbie: Good tip, thanks.  I modified my answer to include your recommendation.

Comment: + 1 for mentioning the template function

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, from the understanding on your question is that your desired function would look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/czAHJ/

To explain things a bit more, take a look at the code...

The HTML is simple, just the drop down and the results container:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>select</option>
    <option value="fruits"> fruits</option>
    <option value="flowers"> flowers</option>
</select>
<div id="myResults"></div>
```

Then the Javascript/jQuery code to add the functionality:

```
// wrap code in $(document).ready(), unless
// you are certain that script is loaded after DOM
$(document).ready(function () {

    var myFruits = ["apple","orange","banana"];
    var myFlowers= ["rose","tulip","carnation"];

    // use bind() as it's faster than click(),
    // also fire on 'change' instead
    $('#mySelect').bind('change', function () { 

        // get value of the select to get our list
        // we dont need any jquery (bit faster)
        var list = false;
        if (this.value == 'fruits') {
            // use fruits
            list = myFruits;
        } else if (this.value == 'flowers') {
            // use flowers
            list = myFlowers;
        } else {
            // unknown, just ignore.. 
            // lets clear the result container..
            // or you can do something else: alert('Unknown Option');
            $('#myResults').html('');
            return false;
        }

        // require list
        if (list) {

            // collect html, use an array
            // its faster than concating to a string
            var html = [];

            // build html list from array (loop *could* be faster...)
            var len = list.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                // add our string to the html array using .push
                html.push('<li>' + list[i] + '</li>');   
            }

            // put our array of html back into a string
            // also, wrap it in a <ul>
            html = '<ul>' + html.join('') + '</ul>';

            // write html list to results, replacing old content
            $('#myResults').html(html);

        }

    });


});
```

Let me know if this is the answer that you are looking for. I've tried to optimize the code as much as possible to keep things fast and light. (Best Practice)

Cheers!